# php MySQL : Split full name and insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, import, split

I have excel file with column called full name i want to import excel file to MySQL and split full name in the file to first name and last name in database

Comment: You can use `explode` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) but what if the person has 3 names? Or is a Jr/Sr/III?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$names = explode(" ", $fullName);
$firstName = $names[0]; // First
$lastName = $names[1]; // Last
```